# Unable to import module SWXMLHash

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swxmlhash

Running Xcode 9.3

I cloned the repo, opened the workspace and let the playground run.

I got an error:

> No such module 'SWXMLHash'

So I closed down everything and ran again on the simulator. Received the same error.

I then tried bringing the framework into an existing project as a cocoapod. Again I was met with

> No such module 'SWXMLHash'

Comment: No offence, just to be sure - your are using the `xcworkspace` generated by Cocoapods, right?

Comment: None taken. Yes - using the workspace generated by cocoa pods. Were you able to compile this framework without issue?